# How to resolve root rendering issue with window size set in useState after server render?

Tags: reactjs, use-state, themeprovider

After deployment to server and testing in Gatsby with `gatsby clean && gatsby build && gatsby serve` whenever root (`https://foobar.com/`) is visited anything that relies on my `ThemeProvider` for dimensions doesn't render correctly.

After debugging I've isolated my issue down to how my `useState` is hard set with a value of `0`:

```
 const [size, setSize] = useState({
    windowWidth: hasWindow ? window.innerWidth : 0,
    windowHeight: hasWindow ? window.innerHeight : 0,
  })
```

full code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const hasWindow = typeof window !== 'undefined'

const useWindowDimensions = () => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState({
    windowWidth: hasWindow ? window.innerWidth : 0,
    windowHeight: hasWindow ? window.innerHeight : 0,
  })

  const updateSize = () =>
    setSize({
      windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
      windowHeight: window.innerHeight,
    })

  useEffect(() => (window.onresize = updateSize), [])

  return size
}

export default useWindowDimensions
```

which gets passed to my `ThemeProvider`:

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react'

// Utils
import useWindowDimensions from '../utils/useWindowDimensions'

const defaultContext = {
  windowWidth: 0,
  windowHeight: 0,
}

export const ThemeContext = createContext(defaultContext)

const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { windowWidth, windowHeight } = useWindowDimensions()

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ windowWidth, windowHeight }}>{children}</ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default ThemeProvider
```

and if I hard set my `useState` values:

```
  const [size, setSize] = useState({
    windowWidth: hasWindow ? window.innerWidth : 1600,
    windowHeight: hasWindow ? window.innerHeight : 1600,
  })
```

my site renders fine in the browser but this is technically wrong if viewed with a mobile device or the browser is smaller than `1600px`. Whenever I navigate to anywhere else in the site the `useState` is updated and there isn't an issue.

Omitting the ternary check for window and hard setting `useState` to:

```
const [size, setSize] = useState({
  windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
  windowHeight: window.innerHeight,
})
```

produces an expected server rendering error:

> "window" is not available during server side rendering.

after `gatsby build`.

How should I be setting my `useState` window dimensions after server load so that my site will pass the correct values to the `ThemeProvider` and render everything correctly when root is visited?

Comment: possibly could just do an update them provider on first render of the app to reset it to window dimensions if you don't find another way.

Comment: Have you tried modifying your custom hook `useEffect` like so: `window.addEventListener("resize", updateSize)`?

Comment: I have but the issue is during the initial setting of the useState

Comment: What I would do in this case is initialize the state with `undefined`, then inside `useEffect`, add the event listener AND actually execute the `updateSize` function so the state is updated as soon as possible.

Comment: Why not make it an answer then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this slight modification and let me know if that works. In your `useWindowDimensions` custom hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const useWindowDimensions = () => {
  const [size, setSize] = useState({
    windowWidth: undefined,
    windowHeight: undefined
  })

  const updateSize = () =>
    setSize({
      windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
      windowHeight: window.innerHeight,
    })

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", updateSize);
    updateSize();

    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateSize);
  }, [])

  return size
}

export default useWindowDimensions
```

Your `Context`:

```
const defaultContext = {
  windowWidth: undefined,
  windowHeight: undefined,
}
```

Comment: I like this approach. Slight error so made an edit and thanks for the answer. In testing and in prod it's functional.